# Cordova FontAwesome fonts not found

Tags: android, cordova, fonts

I have added FontAwesome to my cordova app. project. I use AngularJS with Cordova using [angularjs generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-angularjs-cordova). In browser everything works fine but if I build&run it on android device, FontAwesome icons don't show up.

Per `chrome://inspect/#devices` I see this error output:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///home/username/workspace/cordova/appname/app/fonts/fontawesomewebfont.woff
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///home/username/workspace/cordova/appname/app/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///home/username/workspace/cordova/appname/app/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg
```

My fonts are included in `appname/app/fonts` directory and `font-awesome.css` includes

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

How can I change those absolute paths?

Comment: Are the fonts inside the www folder?

Comment: yes they are in `appname/www/fonts` folder folder

Comment: Have a look at the error output, there is no www folder listed, so the path in the css is wrong.

Comment: if I change it to paths like this `../www/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot` etc. it doesn't work in browser too. Error output remains the same.

Comment: The font import path is relative to the css file, maybe that helps.

Comment: I know, there is my project structure:  [figure 1](http://postimg.org/image/dwl132j5f/),  [figure 2](http://postimg.org/image/xc9wm7lol/).

Comment: The important image. ;-)) The css and font folder has to be inside of www. Otherwise the webview of cordova cannot access it. And remember to change the css path in your index.html also.

Comment: `bootstrap-social.css` is in  `app/css` only and webview of cordova apply all styles defined there. If I copy my `css` folder to `www` and then I run `cordova build/run android`, `css` folder is removed. It seems that everything in `www` is auto-generated. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did something wrong, but what? ;-))

1. Your developer files (index.html, css, js, images, fonts, …) have to be in the top www folder. This is the only place, where you have to put all this files. Files outside of the www folder will be ignored.
2. If you build the app by cordova build, the www folder will be copied into the platform www folders. Cordova will add some cordova specific files, but it will not change your personal files.
3. Cordova itself can only access files inside of the www folder. If you have files outside, you have to use the file plugin.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use AngularJS with Cordova using [angularjs generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-angularjs-cordova). This project has different structure than raw cordova project.

Comment: I don't know this tool, but there seams to be the problem. On github some people have similar problems with image paths. It's critical to use those tools, if something will change in cordova internal those tools will break.

Comment: You are right. I am going to find another way to use AngularJS with Cordova.